# Google Action Disconnect Issue after several weeks in Google Home

Tags: google-smart-home

One of our customer using the 'Habitat HomeLink' launched year ago, They have been observing after using for a month thermostat devices disconnects in google home and they have to re-link their devices in order to work again.This keeps happening after several weeks.

Please let me know the cause for this issue or any suggestion on this.

Expected the devices stay connected in google home even after many months

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Access Tokens are expiring after a month, and your service has an issue renewing the Access Token from a Refresh Token.

A refresh token might stop working for one of these reasons:

- The user has revoked the app access.
- The refresh token has not been used for 6 months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control policies in effect.

A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

More information in this regard can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration).